# how to setup foreign key relationship in entity framework code first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have three entities, User, Domain and Role.

I have this class to define the relationship of the three entities:

```
public class UserDomainRole
{
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int DomainId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

So how to I setup a foreign key relationship between UserDomainRole and other three table?
Is it something like this?

```
public class DeniedDomainRole
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int DomainId { get; set; }
    public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then entity framework will work the relationship out?

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you an exception with a message "Unable to determine composite primary key ordering"

In code first if you want to create a composite primary key then you have to use the to give the key/column order, like that:

```
[Key, Column(Order=1)]
```

Where

**Order =  The composite Primary key/column order on the table**

```
public class UserDomainRole
{
        [Key, Column(Order=1)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order=2)]
        public int DomainId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order=3)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

> So how to I setup a foreign key relationship between UserDomainRole and other three table? Is it something like this?

It is depending on what kind of the relationships you have:

- Configure One-to-Zero-or-One Relationship:

Here, we will configure One-to-Zero-or-One relationship between two entities, e.g. Entity1 can be associated with zero or only one instance of Entity2.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

- Configure One-to-Zero-or-One Relationship:

Here, we will configure One-to-Zero-or-One relationship between two entities, e.g. Entity1 can be associated with zero or only one instance of Entity2.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

- Configure Many-to-Many relationship:

Here, we will learn how to configure Many-to-Many relationship between the Student and Course entity classes. Student can join multiple courses and multiple students can join one course.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Hi Bassam, realised that now, I run the command Add-Migration AddDeniedDomainRole and a c# class is created which include the right migration code. However, when I run my code, it gives me this error:  The model backing the 'XXX' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.  What can I do to make entity framework to update the tables as the migration code has been generated?

Comment: you have to call first update-database or just delete the db with any tool like ssm

Comment: ok, I will give a try. Also do you know why in my migration code, the migration code added this line: RenameTable(name: "dbo.DomainRole", newName: "RoleDomain"); I thought it is not needed so I commented out this line in the migration file, however, I got an error when I try to do a query "Invalid object name 'dbo.RoleDomain'". I tried to search my code, everything still uses DomainRole, not RoleDomain?

Comment: write all your entities in the question and the db context

Comment: return Db.Roles
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(r => !r.IsDeleted && 
                            r.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == userId) &&
                            ((productId == 1 && r.Name.Equals("User Admin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) || r.Domains.Any(d => d.DomainId == domainId)))
                .Select(r => r.Name)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can relation with the user model

```
public int? UserUserId{get;set;}
public virtual User User{get;set;}
```

? makes nullable your foreignkey.